# Opening files in Python to view individual bits

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, image-processing

I want to, as the title says, open a file with python in a binary mode I initially tried this with the 'rb' [open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) method but this just returns data like [this](https://pastebin.com/ndjnYbAE) instead what I'm looking for is this:

```
01010101101001
```

Comment: Your question is very vague. What is the point of this? Most people look at binary files in hex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use python built-in [base64](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html) library.

```
import base64

with open('/path/to/file','rb') as imageFile:
    str = base64.b64encode(imageFile.read())

imageBytes = base64.decodebytes(str)
imageBinary = "".join(["{:08b}".format(x) for x in imageBytes])

print(imageBinary)
```

will result in something like:

```
0011111110111011011110111011100000
```

Details can be seen on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43207978/python-converting-from-base64-to-binary).